# To run selenium server

Tags: selenium-rc

When I try to run `server(rc)` in command prompt it is saying it is already used. So, I run the server in 5555  and changed the same in script. However, it still shows

```
WARN - Failed to start: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444
```

Comment: Do you want to start the hub or the node? To start the node you need to start the hub first.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to stop the server using the below link?

**http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer**

Just open the above link in the browser you are using to run the tests.

After the opening the above link, the selenium server stops.

Then you can proceed with starting the server from port 4444.

Answer (score 0):

Close the browser that is running on port 4444 and then restart the selenium server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
type this instead

```
webdriver-manager --seleniumPort 4455 start
```

it will start it on port 4455 (you can try different numbers as well)